ERROR in [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'. Can i change the permission without changing it in Dockerfile
permission issue
I'm trying to deploy a react application on openshift dedicated on developer sandbox, but one of my deployment is facing the permission denied issue. This is what got when I check the linux user, may be because of this i'm facing issue
    /client$ oc exec -it client-74c796c76f-j4t5j -- /bin/sh
    /app $ whoami
    1007390000
    /app $ cat /etc/passwd
    1007390000:x:1007390000:0:1007390000 user:/:/sbin/nologin

I don't have dockerfile, only have container image of client deployment,and below provided logs of the client deployment
Failed to compile
  [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'
  LOG from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js sass-loader           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss- loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/assets/scss/themes.scss
  <w> Deprecation Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
  <w> In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
  <w> To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
  <w> To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
  <w> More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent
  <w>
  <w> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/vendor/_rfs.scss 57:14 divide()
  <w> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss 59:12 row-cols()
  <w> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss 85:13 @content
  <w> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss 68:5 media-breakpoint-up()
  <w> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss 72:5 make-grid-columns()
  <w> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss 32:3 @import
  <w> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 19:9 @import
  <w> src/assets/scss/config/default/bootstrap.scss 5:9 @import
  <w> src/assets/scss/themes.scss 2:9 root stylesheet
  <w>
  ERROR in [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'

So, can i change the permission without changing into the dockerfile? I'm expecting that it should run somehow without changing the permission in dockerfile, because i don't have access to it. Do you have any alternate way, so that permission issue can be fixed.
Thanks in advance
@ariashahdadi I tried the command that you mentioned, but I'm not able to give the permission to that folder. It is giving error as operation not permitted.
$ oc exec -it client-5568d6f9c5-d6m7j -- chown -R 1000:1000 
 
   chown: /app/node_modules/.bin/acorn: Operation not permitted
   chown: /app/node_modules/.bin/ansi-html: Operation not permitted

Update
This is the Dockerfile that i'm using for creating react application
FROM node:18.16.0

# Create directory for the application and set permissions
#RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && \
 #   chown -R node:node /home/node/app
#WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY . /home/node/app
# Set group permissions for the directory
RUN chgrp -R 0 /home/node/app && \
    chmod -R g=u /home/node/app

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Copy package.json files
COPY . ./

# Switch to non-root user
USER 1000

# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install --ignore-engines
RUN yarn add bootstrap@5.2.3

# Copy application files and set permissions
COPY --chown=node:node . ./
COPY ./env.sh .
COPY .env .
RUN chmod +x env.sh

# Expose port and set entrypoint
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "start", "./env.sh"]


If I switch to non-root user before installing dependencies, I'm getting the build error like below.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
error Could not write file "/home/node/app/yarn-error.log": "EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/node/app/yarn-error.log'"
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/node/app/node_modules'".
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install --ignore-engines' returned a non-zero code: 1

If I use it after the installation I'm getting error after deployment of client pod on openshift like
ERROR in [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache

you can change the permission but every time your container get removed you should run the command again you can exec into container like this
docker exec -it container_id chown -R {USER}:{USER} .

@AriaShahdadi, I tried the command that you mentioned, but i'm getting operation not permitted error.
 oc exec -it client-5568d6f9c5-d6m7j -- chown -R 1000:1000  /app/node_modules/
chown: /app/node_modules/.bin/acorn: Operation not permitted   chown: /app/node_modules/.bin/ansi-html: Operation not permitted   chown: /app/node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer: Operation not permitted

can you run this one docker exec -u 0 -it  container_id chown -R {USER}:{USER} .
dont skip the dot at the end

@AriaShahdadi, I'm working in openshift, this command is not working for me. I tried with oc command with dot at the end., even that also results in error.
$ oc exec -it client-65cf94759f-87q98 -c client -- chown -R newuser:newuser .
chown: changing ownership of './env.sh': Operation not permitted  ```

@AriaShahdadi,  Now i have access to dockerfile of client, i created the new user and also tried with existing user and root also. But openshift is not allowing to create directory. Why it need to create  /app/node_modules/.cache  directory. why it is not allowing?
